# Adding OpenCV CUDA support after installation

Tags: software-installation, cuda, opencv

I am having a problem. I installed openCV 2.4.10 following this tutorial.
http://www.sysads.co.uk/2014/05/install-opencv-2-4-9-ubuntu-14-04-13-10/

At the moment of installation I did not enabled the CUDA support.

Question:
Is there anyway in which I can install the the Nvidia CUDA SDK and reconfigured OpenCV in order to use the gpu supported functions in openCV?

My System Info:
OS: Ubuntu 14.04 [3.13.0-45-generic]
Nvidia Card: Nvidia GTX860M